How does ip link set v-ethn netns <target-namespace> work at a syscall level?
I'm having trouble reading the iproute2 sources and am not sure which syscalls and which options are involved when a virtual ethernet interface is moved from one network namespace to another in Linux.
I tried reading the source and failed to navigate past the parsing. I also tried reading through ioctl options but couldn't find what I was looking for.

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383760/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-bin-ip: "the iproute2 utilities use Netlink sockets to communicate with the kernel." It doesn't use ioctl().

Barmar answered my question: the iproute2 utilities use the Netlink interface.
